# Контролируемый прыжок в 2D платформере

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Как сделать контролируемый прыжок пробелом в Unity? Нужно, чтобы чем дольше держишь пробел, тем выше прыгал персонаж. Я вроде так сделал, но высота прыжка постоянно разная, не знаю почему так происходит. Хотелось бы, чтобы это нормально работало.

```
isGround = Physics2D.OverlapBox(player.position + new Vector3(0, 0.01f, 0), new Vector2(0.065f, 0.01f), 0, LayerGround);
if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { maxYpos = player.position.y + JumpHeight; isJump = true; }
if (player.position.y > maxYpos || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) isJump = false;
if (isJump) rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введите параметр - время во время которого нажатие кнопки прыжок, добавляет силу.(MaxJumpTime) в дальнейшем лучше перевести её в MaxJumpHeight.

```
  [Header("Behavior")]
    public float JumpPower = 0.25f;
    public float MaxJumpTime = 0.25f;

    private float _StoreMaxTime;
    private bool jumping = false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [Header("Settings")]
    public LayerMask mask;
    public float CheckExstends;


    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _StoreMaxTime = MaxJumpTime;
    }

    void Update () {

        var isGround = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down , 1 * CheckExstends, mask);


        if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            MaxJumpTime = _StoreMaxTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && MaxJumpTime > 0)
        {
            MaxJumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && !isGround)
        {
            MaxJumpTime = -1;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + (Vector3.down * CheckExstends));
    }
```

Из редактора, надо

- Обновить слой, чтобы соответствовал слою земли.
- Выставить значение CheckExstends (Gizmo - бела линия в окне редактора) Это проверка на касание с землей. Линия должна едва
  выходить за пределы объекта.

Comment: Происходит тоже самое - высота прыжка каждый раз разная. Иногда чуть больше, иногда чуть меньше. Я думаю это связано с AddForce. Можно ли заменить AddForce на что-нибудь другое?

Comment: JumpPower меняется где то еще?

Comment: Нет, не меняется

Comment: Момент, проверяю кое что, есть подозрения что это проверка Grounded/

Comment: Так и есть, я заменил AddForce на velocity, результат такой же. Как можно по-другому проверять стоит ли персонаж на земле?

Comment: var isGround = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down); работает отлично, разве что слой добавить, при необходимости.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Скрипт кидается на объект. Т.к. не знаю ваших настроек потребуется 2 предварительные настройки . описал их выше

Comment: Можно ли отследить изменение координаты Y, чтобы сделать что-то вроде этого isGound = (если Y не изменяется, то тру)

Comment: Не заметил ответ, сейчас попробую, то что выше

Comment: Только что заметил что вам нужен скрипт для 2д , внес соотвествующие правки.

Comment: Странно, но ничего не меняется. Мне кажется, что дело в AddForce или неточности выполнения скрипта, т.е. будто выполняется то,что быстрее и из-за этого то прибавляется в конце прыжка сила, то нет. Или персонаж застревает в коллайдере земли. Хотя если делать неконтролируемый прыжок, то высота прыжка одинаковая

Comment: Такое возможно, варианты решения - обнулять скорости при приземлении. Или другой , менее вероятный сценарий, переносить обработку из покадрового(update) в фиксированный по времени (fixed update).

Comment: Я вернул старый код и переместил эту строчку *if (isJump) rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpPower));* в FixedUpdate Стало лучше. Высота прыжка почти всегда одинаковая, но теперь иногда подпрыгивает выше чем обычно. Обнуление скорости при приземлении не помогает. Я так понял теперь в конце полета иногда успевает 1 раз срабатывать AddForce и это происходит после этой проверки *if (player.position.y > maxYpos || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) isJump = false;*

Comment: Если идти по абсолютным координатам то проверяя player.position.y > maxYpos  можно и скорость по y рубить, тогда выше головы не прыгнет